# High Cpu usage in javafx

Tags: javafx, webview, cpu-usage

My program loads a webpage and i do not want to let user load webpage (for example : if i load google.com i do not want let load yahoo.com) .
my program execute correctly but cpu usage is very high when run my program because of this part of my code:

```
wv.getEngine().locationProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if(!newValue.contains(oldValue)){
            wv.getEngine().load(oldValue);
        }
    });
```

When i close my program i see its steel running in task manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not closing your application.

```
class zzz extends Application{
  public static void main (String[] args){
    Launch(args);
  }
  public void start(Stage s){
    // bla di bla

   s.setOnCloseRequest((event) -> {// <----------- this is what you need
     Platform.exit(); 
  }

}
```

... you should restart your pc(or kill all the java processes you're starting), apply this fix to actually close your applications, and it will reduce your CPU load because you won't have stray runtimes